# Click inside Loop issue - Remove dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript

The following code takes all the links onto the page that contains "https" and not "google.com" and turns them into iFrames. While that works, the close button that each is iFrame is supposed to be paired with does not work. When you click close, it only closes the last iFrame element on the page. I prefer to be able to do this in vanilla JavaScript, as opposed to jQuery.

```js
total = []
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("https") != -1 && 
 link.href.indexOf("google.com") == -1) {
    var hey = (links[i].href);
    console.log(link.href);
    total.push(links[i].href);
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = hey;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var close = document.createElement('button');
    document.body.appendChild(close);
    close.innerHTML = "close";
    close.addEventListener('click',function(){
      console.log("click");
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      document.body.removeChild(close);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `total = []` without a `const` ? Why?

Comment: Putting both ```document. body. appendChild  ``` to the end of if scope, should work.

Comment: @Borecjeborec1 I'm sorry, but would you be able to submit an answer with that change? Perhaps I did it wrong, but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [**Variable Hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) issue
where the  `var` is hoisted to the closest scope, in your case it's `window` (since you don't have any other parent function wrapper), and reassigned/**overridden** again and again inside the loop - always leading to the **last** iterated element.

**Quickfix**:
`var iframe` and `var close` should be defined as `const` to remain inside the **scope** of that `for` loop *body*:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("https") != -1 && link.href.indexOf("google.com") == -1) {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  // Quickfix
    iframe.src = links[i].href;
    iframe.id = Math.random();
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    const close = document.createElement('button');   // Quickfix
    document.body.appendChild(close);
    close.innerHTML = "close " + link.href;
    close.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
      document.body.removeChild(close);
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://wikipedia.com"></a>
<a href="https://placekitten.com"></a>
```

**The proper way**

not only it's a bad habit to use `var` nowadays, it's also a bad practice to assign Event handlers inside a `for` loop. So here's a remake which removed completely the `var` keyword, uses some nifty reusable DOM utility functions, and at last — the [NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const EL    = (sel, par)  => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS   = (sel, par)  => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Task:
// Convert all http/s anchors to iframes with a 
// button "Delete", wrapped inside a .figure DIV Element

ELS("a").forEach(EL_anchor => {

  const href = EL_anchor.href;
  
  if (/^https?:\/\/(?:(?:www\.)?google.com)/.test(href)) return;

  const EL_figure = ELNew("div", {className: "figure"});
  const EL_iframe = ELNew("iframe", {src: EL_anchor.href});
  const EL_delete = ELNew("button", {type: "button", textContent: "Delete", onclick() {EL_figure.remove();}});

  EL_figure.append(EL_iframe, EL_delete);
  EL("body").append(EL_figure);
});
```

```html
<a href="https://wikipedia.com"></a>
<a href="https://placekitten.com"></a>
```

See the above's RegExp [Example and desctription on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oiOTsu/3)

Answer (score 1):

JS is not my primary language, but try this:

```
total = []
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    if (link.href.indexOf("https") != -1 && link.href.indexOf("google.com") == -1) {
        var hey = (links[i].href);
        console.log(link.href);
        total.push(links[i].href);
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = hey;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        var close = document.createElement('button');
        document.body.appendChild(close);
        close.innerHTML = "close";
        close.addEventListener('click',function(){
            console.log("click");
            document.body.removeChild(iframe);
            document.body.removeChild(close);
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("iframe"));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but try this"* cannot be a valid explanation of the changes you made. Please [edit] and improve your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. If you click any "close" button, it only removes the last iFrame still.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
```

Change `var` to `let`.

OR

Use `forEach` instead of `for` loop.

The reason of this is scoping. `var` is function-scoped. Because above loop runs inside one function, `var` remains common for all loop iteration. On the other side, `let` or `const` are block-scoped. Because `for` loop creates individual blocks, each of the blocks created by the loop will work with an individual variable. `forEach` also creates individual scope. All variables will have values independent from each scope

Comment: There's absolutely no issue in using `for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)`. It's a variable hoisting issue **inside** the loop. FYI: it's regarding `var iframe` and `var close` that should be defined as `const` to remain inside the scope of that `for` loop.

Comment: @RokoC.Bulja Thank you! That change worked.

Comment: @WYXZANDER You're welcome. I provided also an answer as well, with a quickfix and a better way to do stuff.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want to create an `<iframe>` based on the `href` of pre-existing `<a>`s. You also want a `<button>` for each `<iframe>` that closes it.

In the example below are two functions:

- `linksToIframes(urlFrag)`

  - Creates a box to put `<iframe>`s and `<button>`s into. Throwing them on `<body>` is messy:

    ```
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', `<fieldset></fieldset>`);
    const box = document.querySelector('fieldset');
    ```
  - Given a fragment of a url, it will collect all `<a>` into a HTMLCollection:

    ```
    const links = document.links
    ```
  - Convert HTMLCollection into an array and iterate through it finding any matches of `href` and `urlFrag`:

    ```
     [...links].forEach(link => {
       if (link.href.includes(urlFrag)) {...
    ```
  - Any match create the `<frame>` and `<button>` in the `<fieldset>` (the `box`):

    ```
       let iF = document.createElement('iframe');
       iF.src = link.href;
       box.appendChild(iF);
       ...
    ```
- `closeIframe(event)`

  - An event handler that enables any `<button>` to remove the `<frame>` before it and itself:

    ```
    const clicked = e.target; // This is the tag user actually clicked
    if (clicked.matches('button')) { /* <button> is the only 
                                    tag that's accepted (that's 
                                    Event Delegation) */
     clicked.previousElementSibling.remove();
     clicked.remove();
     ...
    ```

Because of event bubbling we can bind the event handler ***on the parent element*** of all of the `<button>`s and then delegate how they react to a click. That's far better than an event handler on each `<button>`.

If you stick to your OP code, `.previousElementSibling.remove();` applied to each `<button>` and `.remove()` to itself should fix it.

```js
const linksToIframes = urlFrag => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', `<fieldset></fieldset>`);
  const box = document.querySelector('fieldset');
  const links = document.links;
  [...links].forEach(link => {
    if (link.href.includes(urlFrag)) {
      let iF = document.createElement('iframe');
      iF.src = link.href;
      box.appendChild(iF);
      let btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.textContent = 'Close';
      box.appendChild(btn);
    }
  });
};
const closeIframe = e => {
  const clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.matches('button')) {
    clicked.previousElementSibling.remove();
    clicked.remove();
  }
}

linksToIframes('https://example.com');
document.querySelector('fieldset').onclick = closeIframe;
```

```css
a,
iframe,
button {
  display: block
}

iframe {
  width: 95%;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href='https://example.com'>EXAMPLE</a>
<a href='https://stackoverflow'>SO</a>
<a href='https://example.com'>EXAMPLE</a>
<a href='https://example.com'>EXAMPLE</a>
```